# Is it Possible to send sms through my smart phone that is connected to network but not to pc using C# application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I Want to create a application that accepts User Mobile Number and the text to be send, I want to send message through my Mobile Number (that is from my windows smart phone.) but that is not connected to pc. Is that possible if yes please provide me the link or tutorials to do that.

Comment: I am looking to send message through mobile phone (GSM Modem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program is running on the PC and the phone is not connected then no, there is no way the PC can talk to the phone. (Even if it is, you still have to work out how your PC will tall the phone to send an SMS message.)

However, it may be possible to achieve the same effect. There are companies which provide internet-based SMS gateways: you use their web site to send an SMS message. Depending on the gateway, it may be possible to make the message appear to come from your phone (the CLI string in all phone messages is configurable at some level and is not set by hardware). That would be down to the particular gateway.

Comment: Then The possible methods to send message from c# application or asp.net are : (1) SMS Gateway (2) Or via connected gsm modem

Comment: Rather then that is there  any other option

Comment: Other than getting a PCI card that acts like a phone for the PC (I don't know if one even exists) then I can't think of any other way of doing it.